# Maven BOM dependencies in Gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle

Given that there is a BOM listed in the dependency management of a Maven project *Foo* like this:

```
<groupId>someGroup</groupId>
<artifactId>someArtifact-bom</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<type>pom</type>
<scope>import</scope>
```

but this BOM comes only into play for a test dependency in a sub-module.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>someGroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>someArtifact</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

The artifact declared in the BOM and BOM itself are only available by declaring an additional repository.

If I create a new Maven project and declare the dependency to *Foo* it gets resolved.

In case I define the very same dependency to *Foo* in a Groovy project

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  implementation("myOrg:Foo:1.0")
}
```

The resolve fails with

```
- Could not resolve myOrg:Foo-parent:1.0.
  - Could not parse POM <mvn-central>/myOrg/Foo-parent-1.0.pom:
    - Could not find someGroup:someArtifact-bom:1.0-SNAPSHOT.
```

...because it does not exist on central.

Of course it can get easily solved by adding the repository, if accessible from the user's project, or putting the BOM and its declared artifacts on central.

I wonder if there are another approach that I couldn't come up with to avoid this problem in the future. An exclude on the dependency definition does not work for BOMs. I can understand this behaviour because a BOM is not a *real* module.

Just for completeness: After a correct resolve there is no dependency regarding the BOM or its artifact in my project. It is really not needed at all.

Comment: Gradle 5.x or later supports BOM. The BOM only provides version info so you will have to add dependencies to the actual libraries you want to use as well, but with those you can skip the version number.

Comment: An alternative is to consider https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin

Comment: Do I get it correctly in the consuming maven project you have defined the bom as a dependency via import?

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. I just realized that I used the rather old 5.2.1 release. Upgrade to something 6+ solves the issue. I am right now at the point to figure out when the change / bugfix was created.

Comment: And not, I haven't set any dependencies on the bom (and I do not want them) in the consuming project.

Answer (score 4):

To be complete, what you experienced with Gradle looks like the expected behaviour to me.

Gradle *will not* dynamically add repositories defined by dependencies. This is because it can become a security risk where an added repository could attempt to shadow popular packages with poisoned artifacts.
So the right solution in Gradle is to add the extra repository *when required*.

With a number of changes that went into how Gradle interprets BOMs and loads Maven POM files, it could very well be that since the BOM is not required, more recent Gradle version will happily ignore it.

But the root problem, transitively adding random repositories, will not be done by any Gradle version.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sorry that I did not pointed this out more explicit: In the consuming project, I do not want to know anything about this bom(!) It should, like you said, get happily ignored because it does not even describe a transitive dependency. It sounds very reasonable to me (and I would not at least expect it) that only repository get used I explicitly allowed to get used. This would be a horrifying feature ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment of Corneil du Plessis I took a deeper look in trying out different Gradle versions and a newer one fixed the problem.
Going back later to the original version that made me aware of the problem (5.2.1) it kept resolving the dependency without any error.

To be really sure I cleared the local Gradle caches and re-ran the build with success.

Since I cannot reproduce the issue anymore with either 5.x nor 6.x I am pretty sure that this was related to the cache and the history of Gradle on my machine.

I think it makes sense to answer my question by myself instead of just closing it to leave the information here.